# How to refer to a figure in R markdown

Tags: r, plot, reference, r-markdown

I want to make a reference to a boxplot in R markdown code. I tried to make it on this way but I didn't success:

````
text text text ([Figure 1](#fig1)) text text text

{#fig1}
chunk:
:::
```r 
df$NF <- df$`non-failing heart (NF)`
df$F <- df$`failing heart (F)`
boxplot(df[3:4],
        data=df,
        cex.lab=0.65,
        xlab="Fig. 1 IRE binding activity for non-failing (NF) and failing (F) hearts.",
        ylab="IRE binding activity (%)",
        col="orange",
        border="brown",
        ylim = c(0, 120)
)
```

:::
````

My idea is to give an ID to the figure in the R code but I didn't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Use bookdown. Then you can crossreference figures.

````
text text (fig. \@ref(fig:blabla))

```{r blabla, fig.cap = "caption"}
plot(1:2, 1:2)
```
````

See https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/figures.html for more information

Comment: thanks for trying to help me, I tried your suggestion, but it will be taken as text in this way: **(fig. @ref(fig:blabla)))**

Comment: Is sounds like you are not using a bookdown output format. Choose one of the bookdown output formats and build the book (instead of knitting the Rmd).

Comment: thanks, but you mean that I should define an bookdown output in header ?

Comment: yes, you need to define a bookdown output format in the yaml header